# simple backbone js view not working

Tags: backbone.js, view, model

I just copy pasted my previous code and still my code is not working. I am newbie and all i do is copy and paste from examples. And still its not working.

**index.html**

```
<body>

<div id="date">Loading...</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="model.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="views.js"></script>
</body>
```

**model.js**

```
   var model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url:'date.json',
        model:model,
        parse:function(response){    
        return response;
        }
});
date = new collection();
date.fetch();
```

**view.js**

```
  var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#date'),
    initialize: function(){
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function(eventName) {
    console.log(this.collection.length); //Throwing 0 as output
    }
});
var dateview = new DateView({collection:date});
dateview.render();
```

**date.json**

```
[
{"date":"1288323623006"}
]
```

Comment: instead of doing a _silly copy/pasting_ , you could have done some effort to understand the concept of backbone.js. Please use the tutorials on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a binding for the collections `change`or `reset`event. Also your render method does not do anything to actually render the content into the html.

The `date.fetch` command (without any error handling!) is executed asynchronously, so it is likely to return when the render of the view has already been executed. Thus you will need an apropriate binding for the collections' events, like this:

**view.js**

```
  var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#date'),
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      this.collection.on("change", this.render);
      this.collection.on("reset", this.render);
    },
    render: function(eventName) {
      console.log(this.collection.length); //Throwing 0 as output
      return(this); // used for chaining
    }
});
var dateview = new DateView({collection:date});
dateview.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your flow, you have included model.js where it does a fetch

```
date.fetch();
```

This is an async method, which means it goes off to fetch the data, and javascript continue to run the next line of code.

Then in your view when you do this.collection.length, (which essentially is the date object), this collection may have not been retrieved from the server yet, meaning it is still empty. A proper way to render stuff after fetch is 
1. bind the render to fetch, like Exinteris mentioned

```
date.fetch({reset:true}),
```

this will fire a "reset" event after the collection got response from server. In view.js

```
this.collection.on("reset",this.render);
```

meaning it will render after a reset event is fired.

2. do render in a promise manner. If you are new to this check here 
   [promise](https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-promises)

   ```
   var self=this;
   date.fetch().then(function(){
      self.render();
   });
   ```

   Also, it is always a good practice to do fetch inside a view, not in model.js. For example:

   ```
   var DateCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend(...);
   var DateView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: $('#date'),
       initialize: function(){
           _.bindAll(this, 'render');
           this.collection=new DateCollection();
           this.collection.on('reset',this.render());
           this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
       },
       render: function(eventName) {
           console.log(this.collection.length); //Throwing 0 as output
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Also, it is always a good practice to do fetch inside a view, not in model.js. Thanks for this words. Will work on this manner.